# React: How can I get the closest number in tens, hundreds, thousands... of a given number?

Tags: reactjs, numbers

For some calculations, I need to get the closest number in tens, hundreds, thousands...etc of a given number. Examples:

**1** becomes **10**
**3** becomes **10**
**15** becomes **20**
**36** becomes **40**
**105** becomes **110**
**1009** becomes **1010**
... etc

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple javascript add reminder to number. by using mod of unit digit

Use `roundOff` function from below example pass digit it will return.

```js
function roundOff(num){
   return (10 - (num%10)) + num
}
console.log("round off of 1009",roundOff(1009))
console.log("round off of 105",roundOff(105))
console.log("round off of 36",roundOff(36))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
let i = 105;
let result = (parseInt(i/10, 10)+1)*10;  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Revansiddh answer is really nice, only to 'fullier' answer the question:

```
function roundOff(num, precision = 10){
   return (precision - (num%precision)) + num
}
console.log("round off of 1009",roundOff(1049))
console.log("round off of 105",roundOff(1049, 100))
console.log("round off of 36",roundOff(1049, 1000))
```